# Nested dynamic forms in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am converting ASP.Net Web Form project to MVC, I had a nested datalist in which the child datalist item can have radiobutton list i was listening to OnCheckedChanged event and then getting the item id and updating the DB accordingly,

How can i achieve same in MVC, my model is also two level the parent object list is binded to the parent datalist and child collection is binded to nested datalist.

Comment: Asp.Net Mvc is Asp.Net and what have you tried?

Comment: @MikeSW sorry by ASP.Net i meant Web Forms now i am converting it to MVC, i will update the question

Comment: Sounds like you need to use partial views with jQuery click handlers on the checkboxes and AJAX calls to update them. This might help: http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:loading-partial-view-with-jquery

Comment: @AntP thanks i will certainly look in to it

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"